# How do you execute a cql file using gocql?

Tags: go, cassandra, gocql

If you were to interface directly with Cassandra using cqlsh you could do the following:

```
$ cqlsh
cqlsh:test> SOURCE '/home/me/reset_db.cql'
```

I've tried to do this using gocql several times but I always get an error. For example, running this:

```
filePath := "/home/me/reset_db.cql"
SOURCE_FILE := "SOURCE (?)"
resetErr := session.Query(SOURCE_FILE, filePath).Exec()
```

Produces the following error:

```
line 1:0 no viable alternative at input 'SOURCE' ([SOURCE]...)
```

So what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SOURCE` is a shortcut in cqlsh, not valid CQL command in general.

You'll need to read the file contents into strings and execute them.

Comment: Well that is very disappointing news. Thank you though for that useful bit of information.